# Access last element of this python panda Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a python panda series called `moving_average`.

```
moving_average = df['score'].rolling(window=period).mean()
```

I would like to retrieve the last element of Series `moving_average`. This is what I did.

```
moving_average = df['score'].rolling(window=period).mean()[-1]
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2477, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 765, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: -1
```

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc), otherwise Pandas is looking for an index key labelled as -1 which doesn't exist hence the KeyError.

```
moving_average = df['score'].rolling(window=period).mean().iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

When you are using `head()` do not forget `tail()`

```
df['score'].rolling(window=period).mean().tail(1)
```

Comment: @Wen, thanks for the answer. Using tail returns more than just a number. It returns the name and dtype as well. More than what I need in my context. It is certainly useful to know, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`moving_average = df['score'].rolling(window=period).mean().iloc[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
moving_average = df['score'].rolling(window = period).mean().iloc[-1]
```